# Import a pkcs12 in mac osx Swift

Tags: swift, macos, certificate, keychain

I would need to import a pkcs12 into the osx keychain and make the private key non-extractable

Is this possible?

this is my example code

```
 let keyString = "MIGeMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GMADCBiAKBgQCVXkvZifORfS8VVEp+BQTrnXu2a2+KL+Rw5FPHeSAOXjrS5DoC0GxK29jTKPGkJrg2WOiL/ZSbKvTq8wBUZzoUGaJQ+kzBJ40ShVtbJYGNFixubuKrSjUNQB149t25lxHnJia0i9i1sLfzrPnqPJ4ABf7lnhkTbNt8g/KriwoqmQICAQE="
        let keyData = NSData(base64Encoded: keyString, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
        var hostError: Unmanaged<CFError>?
        guard let hostPrivateKey = SecKeyCreateRandomKey(optionDict as CFDictionary, &hostError) else {
            fatalError(" Could not generate the private key.")
        }
        let passphrase = "Password" as CFString
        let keyDict1 = SecKeyCopyAttributes(hostPrivateKey)
        var keyParams = SecItemImportExportKeyParameters()
        keyParams.version = UInt32(SEC_KEY_IMPORT_EXPORT_PARAMS_VERSION)
        keyParams.passphrase = Unmanaged.passUnretained(passphrase)
        /*
        keyParams.keyAttributes=?? <---- ????
        */
        var inputFormat :SecExternalFormat = .formatPKCS12
        var itemType :SecExternalItemType = .itemTypeUnknown
        var itemsCFArray :CFArray? = nil
        let error = SecItemImport(hostPrivateKey as! CFData , nil, &inputFormat, &itemType, SecItemImportExportFlags(rawValue: UInt32(0)), &keyParams, "login" as! SecKeychain, &itemsCFArray)
```